# jplayer not working in chrome with multiple audio files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

For some reason if I have 7 or more audio files that use jplayer it only plays and displays the time for the first 6 mps3.

Here is the webpage - http://taunton.cassidydns.co.uk/podcast/listen/extraordinary-wisdom-for-everyday-living/ the first 6 are fine but the 7th doesn't work in chrome (fine in firefox etc).

I tried adding solution: "flash,html" but this just broke all of them.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the library then?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on debug mode of jPlayer. According to their [documentation](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/) there are 3 settings that I would play with, these being:

- consoleAlerts
- warningAlerts
- errorAlerts

You can enable them in your code like so:

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_' + location).jPlayer( {
            ready: function () {
              $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
                mp3: file
              });
            },
            play: function() {
                jQuery(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
            },
            consoleAlerts: true,
            warningAlerts: true,
            errorAlerts: true
          });
```

Once they've been enabled upon click on the 7th item, hopefully a message will be logged to your console.

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled debugging.  Where do I look to get the error logs please?

Comment: @DavidCassidy the logs will be printed to the console of your web browsers developer tools. If you're on a PC hit F12 to open them. If you're having trouble with the console, remove the line consoleAlerts: true, and you'll see the errors as alert boxes.